# How to maintain product availability within Elasticsearch/ Opensearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, opensearch, amazon-opensearch, elasticsearch-schema

I'm setting up an eCommerce search system on Elasticsearch with about 6 million product listings across 3000 stores. I need advice on storing availability data efficiently within ES. This data updates frequently, about 100-200 updates per second, and I'm considering bulk ingestion to handle it. Storing availability within ES is crucial because we use pagination, and checking availability outside ES might lead to mismatches in the number of documents per page.

The search scenario involves looking for products like "iphone 15 pro" using text matching and filtering based on metadata like category, color, etc. I aim to display only available products, whether they're available in at least one location or specifically at a certain store (e.g., store_id 123).

To address this, storing all storeIds where a product is available as an array seems simple but would consume 40Gb of storage.

```
{
  product_name: <String>,
  product_id: <Long>,
  availability: [123,234,432,3425,321 ....] // array length can be upto 3000
}
```

I'm exploring alternatives like using one hot encoding or bitset, where each array-index represents a store Id, and the set/unset bit indicates availability. However, I'm unsure how to formulate queries at runtime with this method.

```
{
  product_name: <String>,
  product_id: <Long>,
  availability: [0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0 ....]
                 | | | | | | | | |
                 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8  <- store ids from 1-3000
}
```

I'd really appreciate any insights or optimal solutions—whether it's altering data storage or any other approach I might not be aware of. Thanks!

Comment: Does have one store_id per Elasticsearch document can be an option ? I think it would scale better even if storage required is a bit higher.

Comment: @Jean-PierreMatsumoto Can you elaborate one store_id per Elasticsearch document.
One product can be present in several stores and having 6 M docs * 3000 stores is gonna explode the document count in ES. For optimization of indexing task parent document can contain product details and child doc can contain product availability array. This is still achievable.

Comment: With your array (bitset or not), each change of availability create a new document and mark "deleted" the previous version of document (I assume doc '_id' is 'product_id'). Changing _id to (product_id, store_id) removes this issue. And since most of products are not in the 3000 stores, the number of docs will be much below 6M * 3000.

Comment: @Jean-PierreMatsumoto Totally agree with your point. Here each product document is having around 30 product related fields and ~600 metadata fields used for faceting/ filtering (not all of this is present in all docs). 
Given this, creating docs with all the fields for N stores may result into unnecessary data duplication.

Comment: I see. But with so many fields, Elasticsearch loses a lot of time to renew the availability, juste when 1 store change its status. To speed up (if it's needed), you can try to have two indexes : (1) product_info (2) product_availability.